# how to enter data into SQL server table via a Form in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server

im using SharePoint Designer 2013. need some ideas or source code to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You mention both SPD and source code? With code, it would be a custom web part or SharePoint app (aka add-in), which are both developer tasks.

But this can be done with SPD with no code. Just set up an "external content type". Here's one tutorial, but there are many others:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Though, the above has at least 4 problems.

First, it's using SP 2010, which really shouldn't be a problem as it really hasn't changed much between versions.

Second, it finished without telling you to click on the "create lists and form" button up in the ribbon. Click that button at the end of the process. That will create what looks and feels like a list. The user will be able to add, edit, sort, filter, etc., just like they're using a list, but the data is being read from and written to a database table.

Third, when it has you set up the connection, the screen shot has the "connect with user's identity" option selected. Good luck getting that to work. More realistically, you'll need to configure a service account via the secure store service (which is accessed via central admin, so you may need to get IT involved).

Fourth, after the external content type is created, no one will have permissions to use it. Permissions will need to be granted via central admin.

Another tutorial that is in 2013, but also misses on the other three points
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-external-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013/

Setting the credentials to use the secure store after the secure store was already set up:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556780%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I have an external content type set up. What is the best method to create a form and populate the data into the SQL table?

Comment: Click the "create lists and form" button in the ribbon in SPD. Then, just go back to your site and refresh the page, and you should see a new list. If everything else is set up correctly, that's all you have to do. The list that is created from clicking that button will look and feel like a list, but it will be storing the data in the table (so, just add an item to the list to add a row to the table).